# ¿Como pasar una url en full calendar?

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En mi variable url quiero pasar todos los campos de una consulta nombre apellido paterno y materno pero en la barra de navegacion muestra & "amp;" 
habra una forma de quitarlo

dejo el codigo

```
@section('javascript')
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next ',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay, listWeek'
        },

        eventLimit: true,
        weekends: false, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
        @if(count($citas) > 0)
            events: [
                @foreach($citas as $cita)
                {
                    title: '{{ $cita->folio_cita.' '.$cita->nombre.' '.$cita->apellido_paterno.' '.$cita->apellido_materno }}',
                    start: '{{ $arrcitas[$cita->id]["start"] }}',
                    url: '{{ url('/defensoria/promoventesregistro/nuevopromovente?nombre='.$cita->nombre.'&apaterno='.$cita->apellido_paterno."&amaterno=".$cita->apellido_materno)}}',
                    type: 'GET',

                },

                @endforeach
            ]
         @endif
        });

});
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Creas la `url` como un `string` y los separas con `?`:

```
url: '/defensoria/promoventesregistro/nuevopromovente?nombre='+{{$cita->nombre}}+'?apaterno='+{{$cita->apellido_paterno}}+"?amaterno="+{{$cita->apellido_materno}}+'',
```

**Sugerencia:**

Una mejor opción seria pasarlo por la ruta como lo propone `laravel`:

```
Route::get('defensoria/promoventesregistro/{nombre}/{apaterno}/{amaterno}', 'DireccionDelController@promoventesregistro');
```

En el controlador llamas la `vista` y le envias las variables.

```
public function promoventesregistro($nombre, $apaterno, $amaterno){
    return view ('vista.index', compact('nombre','apaterno','amaterno'));
}
```